# File utility returns Bad system call

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I have a weird error when I'm trying to run the command `file`. For example if I do `file /etc/passwd` I get the following output :

```
[neolex@neolex-manjaro ~]$ file /etc/passwd
/etc/passwd: ASCII text
Bad system call
```

Do you have an idea on how to fix this issue ? When I run `strace` the `SIGSYS` signal comes when it runs `getpid()`:

```
munmap(0x7fbf2d438000, 5818072)         = 0
getpid()                                = ?
+++ killed by SIGSYS +++
Bad system call (core dumped)
```

Comment: Was `file` installed from your distribution? Check the output `type file`. Do other programs abort on `getpid()`? I wonder why `file` would call `getpid`, it doesn't on my machine. Maybe the binary is corrupted, or libc. Does it do this from another account? Have you done a RAM check recently?

Comment: Yes I used pacman to install file, type file gives me "file is /usr/bin/file" but the file in /bin/file is exactly the same. Do you have an exemple of program that call getpid to try it ?
No I didnt do a ram check recently 
edit: I tried a program in c++ that calls getpid and there is no error like /bin/file program

Comment: When I tried to build file myself I get the followiing error  : make[2]: *** [Makefile:830: magic.mgc] Bad system call

Comment: Processes crashing seemingly randomly like that is a possible indication of hardware failure, maybe a failing RAM chip or disk. Check the `dmesg` output (run `sudo dmesg` if necessary) for errors.

Comment: I finally manage to build file and it doesnt get bad syscall now, I added the option  --disable-libseccomp  but I have no idea why it's not working without this option, do you have an idea ? Maybe a protection of my kernel ?

Comment: The seccomp mode allows only a few syscalls. Every other syscall gets the process killed. It does not make any sense for a compiler to activate this if non-allowed syscalls are made later. Seems there is a bug in how this security feature is used.